# WebOS VirtualList Problem

Tags: webos, enyo

In my code i am tring to display my sqlite db in vertual list
and in that code in for loop you can see the commented alerts and they conform that the value i want is which i want from db.

now that value i want to show in vertual list.

I know the solution is like setup data in array and render it but how?
can please replay with edit my code

```
/* Copyright 2009-2011 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, L.P. All rights reserved. */
enyo.kind({
   name: "storage.SQLite",
   kind: HeaderView,
   components: [
      {name: "createDBButton", kind: "Button", caption: "Create Database", onclick: "createDB"},
      {name: "createTableButton", kind: "Button", caption: "Create TABLE1", onclick: "createTable"},
      {name: "fillTableButton", kind: "Button", caption: "Insert a Row into TABLE1", onclick: "fillTable"},
      {name: "queryButton", kind: "Button", caption: "Show TABLE1 Contents", onclick: "doQuery"},
      {name: "results", kind: "HtmlContent"},
      {kind: "VirtualList", name:"myVirtualList", style: "width: 500px; height: 200px;",
      components: [
           {kind: "Item", layoutKind: "HFlexLayout", components: [
              {name: "caption1", flex: 1},
              {name: "caption2", flex: 1},
            ]}
         ]
      }


   ],
   createDB: function() {
      try {
         this.db = openDatabase('SampleDB', '', 'Sample Data Store', 65536);
         this.$.results.setContent("Created database SampleDB.");
      }
      catch (e)
      {
         this.$.results.setContent(e);      
      }
   },
   createTable: function() {
      try {
         this.nullHandleCount = 0;
         //create table 1
         var string = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (col1 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "nothing", col2 TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT "nothing");'
          this.db.transaction(
              enyo.bind(this,(function (transaction) {
               //transaction.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;', []);
                  transaction.executeSql(string, [], enyo.bind(this,this.createTableDataHandler), enyo.bind(this,this.errorHandler));
              }))
          );
      }
      catch (e)
      {
         this.$.results.setContent(e);
      }
   },
   fillTable: function() {

      this.$.results.setContent('0');
      this.nullHandleCount = 0;
      var string = 'INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2) VALUES (" Ajay ","  value2 ");'   
      this.db.transaction(
           enyo.bind(this,(function (transaction) {
               transaction.executeSql(string, [], enyo.bind(this,this.createRecordDataHandler), enyo.bind(this,this.errorHandler));
           }))
       );
   },
   doQuery: function() {
      // Query table1
      var mytext = 'select * from table1;'
       this.db.transaction(
           enyo.bind(this,(function (transaction) {
               transaction.executeSql(mytext, [], enyo.bind(this,this.setupRow), enyo.bind(this,this.errorHandler));
           }))
       );
   },
   createTableDataHandler: function(transaction, results)
   {
      this.$.results.setContent("Created TABLE1.");
   },
   createRecordDataHandler: function(transaction, results)
   {   
      this.$.results.setContent("Inserted 1 record.");
   },
   setupRow: function(transaction, results)
   {

       var string = "";
      try {

         var list = [];
         for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = results.rows.item(i);

            //alert(results.rows.item(i).col1);
            //alert(results.rows.item(i).col2);
            this.$.caption1.setContent(results.rows.item(i).col1);
            this.$.caption2.setContent(results.rows.item(i).col1);

         }

      }
      catch (e)
      {
         this.$.results.setContent(e);
      }

   },
   errorHandler: function(transaction, error)
   {
       this.$.results.setContent('Error was '+error.message+' (Code '+error.code+')');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a virtual Repeater here: https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/enyo/enyo-api-reference.html#enyo.VirtualRepeater

Which has a number of options for callbacks - for example onSetupRow: "someMethod"

You need to call this method... which will populate each row of your grid.

What I do for my resultsset rightly or wrongly is in my override of Create, i will create a variable varResults = [];

I then call a method to query my data e.g.

```
onClickData: function(){

   // Get some data

   this.varResults = recordSet;

}
```

Does this help? p.s. I dont appreciate you emailing my personal email address and asking questions!

Comment: Thanks i got the solution https://developer.palm.com/distribution/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16583